# Contract.Ensures Malformed contract section in method

Tags: c#, code-contracts

Why am I getting this building error "Malformed contract section in method..." on the following code?

```
List<int> MatrizesCorrelacao;

public string lsMatrizes
    {
        get
        {
            if (TudoDataUnica == true)
            {
                return "0";
            }

            Contract.Ensures(Regex.IsMatch(Contract.Result<string>(), @"^(-1)|(\d+(,\d+)*)$"));

            return TransformList<int>ToString(MatrizesCorrelacao);
        }
        set
        {
            MatrizesCorrelacao = TransformStringToList<int>(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `TransformList<int>ToString(MatrizesCorrelacao);` this code isn't valid.

Comment: I just put a phrase to you understand what my function does, but my code is another name.

Answer (score 0):

Like with most of the `Contract` calls, your `Contract.Ensures` has to be at the top of the method.